# Session does not persist across delete/destroy request in Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, session, request, persist

I'm using session to persist data across requests and it works well, except when it is a delete request. In this case, my session is getting destroyed. Does anyone know how to solve that?

I have a session[:navigation] that stores the title of every page to show as breadcrumbs. It works when I navigate from one page to another, but it cleans when I click any delete button (triggering a delete request).

Does delete request normally erase a session? Is there a way to avoid that?

Comment: Your situation is not normal but you'll have to post code/more details for a specific solution

Comment: That is not he normal behavior. Share some code...

Comment: probably a protect_from_forgery issue ...